# Sitecore xDB cannot connect to a MongoDB replica set

Tags: xdb, mongodb

On our Sitecore 8 production instance, we are getting the below error messages. This client site we have recently inherited from another partner and on preliminary investigation from our end, we see they have implemented replica sets for MongoDB

```xml
<add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://{IP}:27017,{IP}:27018/sitecore_analytics?replicaset=SiteCoreDMS" />
```

Which looks correct. These are the errors in Sitecore logs:

```
7056 04:22:01 ERROR Cannot create tracker.
Exception: System.IO.IOException
Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at MongoDB.Bson.IO.ByteBufferFactory.LoadFrom(Stream stream)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument](BsonBinaryReaderSettings readerSettings, IBsonSerializer serializer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.GetFirstBatch(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.<>c__DisplayClass29`1.<FindOneAs>b__28()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.Execute(Action action, ExceptionBehavior exceptionBehavior)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.FindOneAs[TDocument](IMongoQuery query, ExceptionBehavior exceptionBehavior)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbContactStorage.LoadContactIdentifier(ID id)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider.TryLoadContact(ID id, IContactFactory factory, LeaseOwner leaseOwner, TimeSpan leaseDuration)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.TryLoadContact(Guid id, LeaseOwner leaseOwner, TimeSpan leaseDuration)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.TryLoadContact(Guid contactId, Int32 lockDurationMinutes)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.LoadContact.Process(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.EnsureSessionContext()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateTracker.GetTracker.Process(CreateTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Initialize()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)


7056 04:22:01 ERROR Cannot start analytics.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Tracker.Current is not initialized
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking.Process(PipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.HttpRequest.StartAnalytics.Process(RenderLayoutArgs args)

--------------------------------------------

ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/automationRangeManager
Exception: System.IO.IOException
Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at MongoDB.Bson.IO.ByteBufferFactory.LoadFrom(Stream stream)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument](BsonBinaryReaderSettings readerSettings, IBsonSerializer serializer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.GetFirstBatch(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.MongoDbAutomationProvider.GetEarliestAutomationTransitionTimestamp()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Aggregation.Data.Processing.RangeManagerAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

---

Attaching output of rs.status()

```json
SiteCoreDMS:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "SiteCoreDMS",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-10-12T06:49:33Z"),
    "myState" : 2,
    "syncingTo" : "42.159.226.69:27017",
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "42.159.225.222:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 2474004,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1476254930, 1),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-10-12T06:48:50Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-10-12T06:49:32Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-10-12T06:49:31Z"),
                    "pingMs" : 0,
                    "syncingTo" : "42.159.226.69:27017"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "42.159.225.222:27018",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 2474006,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1476254930, 1),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-10-12T06:48:50Z"),
                    "self" : true
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "42.159.226.69:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "uptime" : 2474002,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1476254930, 1),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-10-12T06:48:50Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-10-12T06:49:32Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2016-10-12T06:49:33Z"),
                    "pingMs" : 2,
                    "electionTime" : Timestamp(1474819533, 1),
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-09-25T16:05:33Z")
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
SiteCoreDMS:SECONDARY>
```

Comment: Please log into MongoDB manually (using the `mongo` client) and get replica set configuration using the command `rs.conf()`. Attach the output here.

Comment: SiteCoreDMS:SECONDARY> rs.conf()
{
        "_id" : "SiteCoreDMS",
        "version" : 10,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "42.159.225.222:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "42.159.225.222:27018"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "42.159.226.69:27017"

Comment: }
        ],
        "settings" : {
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                }
        }
}

Comment: Also, could you please edit your question and attach the output of [**`rs.status()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/)?

Comment: See, your primary is on 226.69. That's where your app is going to attempt all writes. It needs to be able to access that ip/port.

Comment: 222.222 and port 27017/27018 is open
226.69 and port 27017 is open but port 27018 is closed
But another question is that I cant see any contact or visits data in analytics mongo DB.

Comment: Of course you cannot see anything there—your application cannot access MongoDB. Please use `mongo.exe` on the server where your Sitecore application is running and try connecting from that server directly to the replica set: `mongo --host SiteCoreDMS/42.159.226.69:27017,42.159.225.222:27017,42.159.225.222:27018 sitecore_analytics`.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi ,
well after checking everything . I gave up and raised a Sitecore support ticket, since I was still assuming this is Ip and ports issue. Then support updated us that this issue had been raised earlier for the Client & that they had provided certain recommendations , out of which , global.asax was inherited from System.web instead of Sitecore.Web.Application. So after certain back and forth , I deployed the updated dll today. So currently from the logs , the connection issues look resolved, but there are other aggregation/Reporting issues , for which I am checking with Support

Comment: Well, when you're sure it's resolved, it would be great if you posted the solution as an answer here!\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the output of `rs.conf()`, you currently have three replica set members: two of them hosted on `42.159.225.222`, and another one on `42.159.226.69`.

You need to make sure that the Sitecore application has direct access to both of these IP addresses via the ports specified. Even though you only have `42.159.225.222` in your connection string, the MongoDB driver may attempt to connect to any server available in the replica set.

Comment: for seconday 226.69 port 27018 is blocked ..

Comment: You don't have a secondary on 226.69:27018.

Comment: I have checked all the ip and ports .. using telnet . Sitecore is able to communicate with Mongo perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Your connectionstring shows two different ports for each server, is that correct? Because [Mongo recommends](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) keeps on the same port for a Replica Set environment

> In a production, deploy each member of the replica set to its own machine and if possible bind to the standard MongoDB port of 27017

Also, are you able to connect from one mongo to another? Please see [the line below](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-replica-sets/#replica-set-troubleshooting-check-connection)

From Server1

```
mongo --host m2.example.net --port 27017
```

From Server2

```
mongo --host m1.example.net --port 27017
```

Please let us know if your results

Answer (score 1):

First of all, could you check if your mongo processes are running?

A good thing to do is check wether your resultset is working properly. Try to run the following command on the commandline and check the output:

```
mongo --eval "db.isMaster()"
```

You should see some output like thus:

```
{
    "hosts" : [
            "host1:27017",
            "host2:27017",
            "host3:27017"
    ],
    "setName" : "DSM",
    "setVersion" : 3,
    "ismaster" : true,
    "secondary" : false,
    "primary" : "host1",
    "me" : "host1",
    "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff00000000000001ff"),
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2016-10-13T14:42:02.398Z"),
    "maxWireVersion" : 4,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "ok" : 1 }
```

When your output looks like that, you can be sure your resultset is working properly.

I that case it could be a simple fix by not writing your connection string with:

?replicaset=SiteCoreDMS

but instead:

?replicaSet=SiteCoreDMS

reviewing the Sitecore connectionstring documentation involving replicasets, i can see the capital S in every string.

Let me know if this worked out for you!